# How can I play older worlds on newer versions of minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the new launcher you can play beta and alpha versions of minecraft. I made a world in alpha 1.2.6 and now I want to take it to beta 1.3.0. But it does not show up in there.

How can I get my world to show up?

Comment: Just tried, and I was able to go from Alpha 1.2.6 to Beta 1.3.0 perfectly fine. The worlds needed converting (done automatically), but they showed up in the list.

Comment: For me they don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each world should have a save folder, located in the `saves` folder in your `.minecraft` directory.

On Windows, it is located in: `%AppData%\.minecraft`.

All you should need to do is move the old save file into the new Minecraft directory folder. When you open your game, the worlds should appear in the list, and then convert to the new version when opened. After that, they'll work as normal.

---

On a side note, using the same seed in newer versions of Minecraft won't work the same way, due to different salts applied and variable used to generate the terrain.

Comment: I'm on my phone atm, so I'll add the directory paths for the minecraft folders later. In the meantime, you should just be able to google them.

Comment: Note any terrain that has already been generated carries over "verbatim". It's just new terrain that won't conform to the same standard on the old seed. (so if you have some specific area in mind, go into "Creative", set draw distance as far as you can and fly all over the map in that mode, letting all the terrain spawn. Then move the save. Note no pre-spawned chests will contain any loot only available in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do this whole world update stuff just download this mod for 1.12.2. I know it says it's a server plugin, but I can 100% guarantee that it will work like any other mod, just download forge for minecraft 1.12.2 and drag this mod into the mod folder, when you're creating a world, select "world type: alpha 1.1.2_01" and then you're done. This mod doesn't generate villages or anything like that, but if you're using mods such as recurrent complex, rouge-like dungeons etc. it will generate those structures. Anyway Here's the link.

https://forums.spongepowered.org/t/nostalgiagen-0-6-generate-minecraft-alpha-beta-worlds-on-your-sponge-forge-server/10126

Comment: I think you might want to re-read the question. He/She doesn't want to generate older worlds on newer versions; he/she wants to use existing older worlds.

Answer (score -6):

There's no possible way unless you change the versions. Because of features, terrains will always look different depending on the seeds. Speaking of seeds, there's no possible seed to generate a old world. Unless you can change the world generation game files of course. So no. There is no way to getting an old world in a new update. Best you change versions or change the files.

Comment: Are you shure you can't do this. At the time the upgrades came out there was no problems. What does an existing world have to do with a seed anyway

Comment: @BRHSM Seeds are used to generate specific worlds. If the game is in a newer version, it won't generate an old world due to features.

Comment: Yes I know but i'm not generating a world i want to take the world I have and upgrade the version of minecraft and still be able to play